# Let $F_n$ be a Fermat prime number prove that $\gamma_{F_n}(2)=2^{n+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

> Let $F_n$ be a Fermat prime number. Prove that $\gamma_{F_n}(2)=2^{n+1}$.

Here $\gamma_{F_n}(2)$ denotes the order of $2$ modulo $F_n$.

**My attempt:**

$F_0=2^{2^0}=2^{0+1} \quad\checkmark$

$F_1=5 \neq 2^{1+1}  $

I don't know why for $n=1$ this is not true

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: The order of $2$ modulu $F_n$

Comment: I never saw $\gamma$, most people write $ord_p(a)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

Comment: $F_n$ does not need to prime,  does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$. So, $F_n|2^\gamma-1$ implies $2^\gamma-1\ge 2^{2^n}+1$, which implies $\gamma\ge 2^n+1$.

Moreover, $F_n=2^{2^n}+1|(2^{2^n})^2-1=2^{2^{n+1}}-1$. Thus, $\gamma|2^{n+1}$.

So, we have $\gamma|2^{n+1}$ and $\gamma\ge2^{n}+1$. Thus, $\gamma=2^{n+1}$